# In C#, how an method can be called on a possibly null instance?

Tags: c#

I was wondering, using an hypothetic `IsNullOrEmpty()` method on a `List` instance (not in .NET Framework), if the instance is effectively *null*, it will throw an *Object reference not set to an instance of an object* exception, or something like this.  Considering this, is it possible to call a method on a *null* instance?

Comment: IsNullOrEmpty() method on a `List` instance!Am afraid there's no such method..

Comment: Where did you see this? Perhaps there's a third-party extension method on `List<T>` there?

Comment: I did not mention that `IsNullOrEmpty()` is a .NET Framework extension for `List`.  It is indeed a *third party* extension method.

Comment: What's the third party library? If you added the name of it to your question you might get more relevant answers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `List<T>.IsNullOrEmpty()` in the CLR.

However, perhaps someone wrote an extension method for List. It would look something like this:

```
public static class ListExt
{
    public static bool IsNullOrEmpty<T>(this List<T> self)
    {
        return (self == null) || (self.Count == 0);
    }
}
```

If so, you can see from the implementation that you can safely pass `null` for the `self` parameter. That would happen with this code:

```
List<int> lint = null;

if (lint.IsNullOrEmpty())
{
    // ...
```

This calls the extension method passing `lint` to it; in this case, it passes `null` and the `(self == null)` check in the implementation will cause `false` to be returned, and will prevent any `NullReferenceException` from being thrown.

Answer (score 12):

There isn't an `IsNullOrEmpty()` for a `List` only `String`. In the latters case it's a *static* method so doesn't need an instance, you pass in a string reference to check and it can check for null there.

Answer (score 6):

Extension methods can take a null "this" parameter.  I don't know of any method IsNullOrEmpty for a List in the Framework, but imagine it would be implemented something like:

```
public bool IsNullOrEmpty<T>(this IList<T> list)
{
    if (list == null) return true;
    return list.Count == 0;
}
```

You can call this (or any other) extension method on a null reference without any problem:

```
List<int> nullList = null;
if (nullList.IsNullOrEmpty())
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: +1 on this my friend, you really answered the underlying question here.

Comment: @AntP, that's fine; and I'll delete my comment now that you've deleted yours. But, FWIW, this statement `FWIW, it seems some ajax calls screwed up the friendly time strings when I first posted as it told me I was 20 seconds ahead.` is still not in the spirit of this forum. When you come up here just to help people, you do a lot more good and get a lot more rep because you have the right motive.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK `IsNullOrEmpty` is only a method of class `System.String`, and is not available for `List`. It is a static method, not an extension method. you call like this:

```
string.IsNullOrEmpty(text);
```

and not like this

```
text.IsNullOrEmpty();
```

Therefore there is no problem checking whether the reference is not set to the instance of an object or not.

Answer (score 1):

It is a static method that takes the instance of the string in question as parameter.

```
public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(
    string value
)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

There is not `IsNullOrEmpty` method in BLC defined for `List`

You could create an extension method easily:

```
namespace System
{
    public static class StringExtensions
    {
        public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(this string s)
        {
            return string.IsNullOrEmpty(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not an extension method.

Comment: Pretty sure it is not in fact an extension method.

Comment: this is not an extension method. and extension method must be part of a static class and have the first parameter start with this

Comment: Sorry, yes, it is just a `static` method on `string`.

Answer (score 1):

As has been pointed out, there is no such method for lists. Easy enough to write an extension method, however:

```
public static bool IsNullOrEmpty<T>(this IList<T> list)
{
     return (list == null || list.Count == 0);
}
```

If you want to throw an exception for nulls:

```
public static bool IsEmpty<T>(this IList<T> list)
{
    if (list == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("list");

    return (list.Count == 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`IsNullOrEmpty()` doesn't support for a `List` it's only for String.Following is the implimentaion of `IsNullOrEmpty` from msdn.

```
result = s == null || s == String.Empty;
```

If you want to check the list you can write your own extension method to do that as following.

```
  public static bool IsNullOrEmpty<T>(this ICollection<T> collection)
    {
        if (collection == null)
            return true;

        return collection.Count == 0;
    }
```